# No HDMI signal after installing and rebooting

Tags: 11.10, hdmi, external-monitor

Until reboot I have a signal via HDMI on my external Monitor.

Afterwards there is nothing - the display-settings shows only one Monitor.

I am using a NVIDIA graphics engine with the latest drivers - I tried all possible drivers.
How can I restore the visibility?

Comment: What happened between boot and reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Between boot and reboot was the ubuntu installation.

I resolved the problem: The NVIDIA XServer must be configured - that´s a little bit tricky when your primary screen is not working properly...

I do not know why everything worked while installing ubuntu...

Comment: Please accept the answer you posted by clicking on the checkmark, or delete your question. This is to help with the **Ask Ubuntu Clean Up** project. Thanks!

Comment: We need you to elaborate.  I upvoted since you fixed it, but you must elaborate on how